# For loop with quoted entries

Tags: for

A for loop that steps through a list of quoted headers:

```
for h in "header" "header 2"; do
    echo $h
done
```

returns

```
header
header 2
```

I'd like to reference the headers somewhere else to clean it up, like assigning them to a variable.

```
headers='"header" "header 2"'
for h in $headers; do
    echo $h
done
```

but this returns

```
"header"
"header
2"
```

as it should.

Is there a way to get around this? It's similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039130/iterate-over-list-of-files-with-spaces) with a list of files with spaces, but I'm not doing files, and I'd like to keep them on one line, as there will be many entries.

Comment: Can you instead use an array instead of string that has to be word split?

Comment: What thrig suggested. In other words, if you use Bash, use `headers=("header 1" "header 2")` and `for h in "${headers[@]}"; do echo "$h" ; done`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of doing this is by changing the fiels seperator variable like:

```
headers="header,header 2"
IFS=,
for h in $headers; do
        echo $h
done
```

**Note:** If you have other loops which requires the default IFS value you can first save the IFS value into a temporary variable.

See also `man bash` and search for `IFS` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I realized a way around this is to use commas (or something else) instead of quotes, and go csv style. Now it's a simple convert to line-delimited.

```
headers="header,header 2"
headers=$(echo $headers | sed 's/,/\n/g')
printf "$headers\n" | while read h; do
    echo $h
done
```

Still, if you have any more elegant solutions, please share.